# VRTs (vector union layers) not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export

I have created a set of VRT's for base mapping vector tile layers following this  [tutorial](http://www.spatialguru.com/create-a-union-vrt-from-a-folder-of-vector-files/)

This works well for displaying the layers but If I want to export or copy out a subset of the features the resulting set of feature is different to what I had selected. When I draw a selection area the selected features don't correspond to the area I have drawn, features 2KM away seem to get selected randomly.

If I do *Project> export dxf* I get the right features/ area I wanted. There is not an option to create a spatial index.

Maybe vectors in VRT just isn't properly supported.

QGIS 2.10.1 OSX 10.11.1

Comment: Can you point where to get sample data and which GDAL commands to use? Ogr2vrt.py seems to be somewhat experimental but I found it here https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples.

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Comment: Which files exactly? Test is useless if we have different data.

Comment: OS Open Map - Local

Comment: I have updated the link to the tutorial as it wasn't working

Comment: Site requires registration and I feel too lazy for that, sorry.